# вопрос про lastIndexOf

Tags: javascript

кто-нибудь может мне объяснить как это работает? какая здесь логика? почему равенство с position выдает уникальные элементы? спасибо

```js
const a = [1, 9, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 8, 0, 9, 0, 1, 5, 3];

const b = a.filter(function(item, position, array) {
  return a.lastIndexOf(item) === position;
});
console.log(a); // [1, 9, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 8, 0, 9, 0, 1, 5, 3]
console.log(b); // [2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 5, 3]
```

Comment: ну потому что в фильтр должно попасть условие которое вернёт true....... а много ли элементов в массиве находятся на одном и том же месте? Вот например у тебя последняя девтяка находится на позиции 10, сколько ещё элементов на позиции 10?

Comment: по мне, так проще в отладке посмотреть что у тебя происходит на каждой итерации

Answer (score 3):

Метод `filter()` создаёт новый массив со всеми элементами, прошедшими проверку, задаваемую в передаваемой функции. Это значит, что если внутри функции какое-то условие вернёт `true`, то элемент попадёт в результирующий массив. Пример.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
let result = array.filter((el, index) => index === 0 || index === array.length - 1);
console.log(result);
```

В результат попали элементы, которые стоЯт на по индексу 0 или на последнем месте. Их, очевидно, всего два.

**[lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)** возвращает последний индекс, по которому данный элемент может быть найден в массиве. Очевидно, что такой индекс может быть только один (вариант, когда ничего не найдено - не рассматриваем). **Всегда один**.

Допустим есть массив `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. `lastIndexOf` в этом массиве **всегда** будет возвращать нам 5. А `filter` нам вернёт только тот элемент у которого 5 === position (index). Получается, что у нас 6 итераций такого вида:

```
return 5 === 0
return 5 === 1
return 5 === 2
return 5 === 3
return 5 === 4
return 5 === 5
```

Из всех условий подойдёт только последнее и вернётся только тот ноль, что стоИт на позиции 5. Другие - не пройдут.

Тоже самое можно рассматривать с любыми числами в любом массиве

Answer (score 0):

Просто доказательство от обратного:

Пусть утверждение "равенство с position выдает уникальные элементы" - неверное. Тогда у нас в результирующем массиве есть 2 элемента с одинаковым значением `x`. Это значит, что в исходном массиве были хотябы 2 `x`, но очевидно на разных позициях

Т.к. мы ищем наибольшую позицию, где находится `x`, то очевидно такая позиция единственная, следовательно может быть всего 1 `x`, который находится на данной позиции, следовательно 2 `x` не могли пройти проверку, следовательно в результирующий массив попадёт только 1 из них, следовательно в результирующем массиве 1 `x`

А это противоречит этому **Тогда у нас в результирующем массиве есть 2 элемента с одинаковым значением `x`**, значит исходное утверждение **"равенство с position выдает уникальные элементы" - неверное** - неверное, значит утверждение **равенство с position выдает уникальные элементы** - верное